# Why the component is rendered again

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, material-ui, render

I have a reducer including:

```
const initialState = {
  openedTabs: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("openedTabs")) || [],
};
    const openTab = (state, action) => {
      let newOpenedTabs = [];
      if (action.tab.singleTab) {
        const current = state.openedTabs.findIndex(
          (t) => t.title === action.tab.title
        );
        if (current !== -1) {
          newOpenedTabs = [
            ...state.openedTabs.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: false })),
          ];
          newOpenedTabs[current].selected = true;
        } else
          newOpenedTabs = [
            ...state.openedTabs.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: false })),
            { ...action.tab, selected: true },
          ];
      } else
        newOpenedTabs = [
          ...state.openedTabs.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: false })),
          { ...action.tab, selected: true },
        ];
      // localStorage.setItem("openedTabs", JSON.stringify(newOpenedTabs));
      return updateObject(state, {
        openedTabs: newOpenedTabs,
      });
    
    };

    const closeTab = (state, action) => {
      const newOpenedTabs = removeItemAtIndex(state.openedTabs, action.index);
      if (action.selectedTab && newOpenedTabs[newOpenedTabs.length - 1]) {
        newOpenedTabs[newOpenedTabs.length - 1].selected = true;
      }
      return updateObject(state, {
        openedTabs: newOpenedTabs,
      });
    };
    
    const selectTab = (state, action) => {
      if (action.index < state.openedTabs.length)
        return updateObject(state, {
          openedTabs: [
            ...state.openedTabs.map((t, i) =>
              i === action.index
                ? { ...t, selected: true }
                : { ...t, selected: false }
            ),
          ],
        });
      else return state;
    };
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.OPEN_TAB:
      return openTab(state, action);
    case actionTypes.CLOSE_TAB:
      return closeTab(state, action);
 case actionTypes.SELECT_TAB:
      return selectTab(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and `updateObject` is:

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
  return {
    ...oldObject,
    ...updatedProperties,
  };
};
```

When I move between tabs, I actually select on the tab, it does not render the component again, but when I delete a tab the component renders again. Does anyone know why?

This is how I use it:

```
const getComponent = (Component, props) => {
   return <Component {...props} />;
};

props.openedTabs.map((tab, i) => (
      <TabPanel
          value={props.openedTabs.findIndex((t) => t.selected)}
          index={i}
          key={i}
          className={classes.tabPanelItem}
       > 
         {getComponent(tab.component, tab.props)}
       </TabPanel>
))
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bit unclear, but are you asking why updating state has triggered a rerender? Since you mention removing/deleting tabs you probably don't want to use array indices as React keys, this will lead to stale UI because React bails on rerenders.

Comment: Yes, I mean ... what can I do so that when I close a tab it does not render again

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't you ***want*** your UI to rerender when you update state to close/add/remove tabs?

Comment: i updated..I tried to explain in the photo..

Comment: Sorry for the unclear of my question

Comment: I think this is the React key issue I mentioned above. Try to assign and use a GUID for each "tab" element object in your state as a React key.

Comment: Can you give a small example?I do not know how to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236508/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-zahra-zamani).